# TableView - Customize Headers in Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I would like to customize the headers in my grouped tableview.

I know I can do this by doing something similar to the following:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                               CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50.0)];

    //configure the UIView

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

I'm new to iOS development and thus far I've only configured my custom views in the storyboad by dragging and dropping the elements that I want to use into my views.

Therefore my question is: Is it possible to customize the look of the header view in the storyboard?

I would like to add buttons to some of the headers for example. Please keep in mind that I would like to use different headers for each of the sections.

Comment: No, its not possible. You need to code for dynamic views. Look at storyboard as collection of your static views. All other dynamic views have to be developed though code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mr_bem said, you can use a XIB file to do this, be aware though that the loadNibNamed method returns an NSArray, your view should be the first one, I implemented it very easily:

[heres a shot of a tableview using a XIB header](http://cl.ly/image/3F2Y0H253Q3D)

Make sure to include the code, the 32.f height comes from the size of the freeform XIB that I created:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 32.f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *headerViewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"headerView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *headerView = [headerViewArray objectAtIndex:0];

    return headerView;
}
```

This is what the XIB looks like -> [header XIB](http://cl.ly/image/1P2i0M0P2q12)

Comment: Thanks for the additional note... I have a '[0]' at the end of the method, that'll also return the same UIView you have ;D

Comment: oops my apologies, I didnt see that!

Answer (score 1):

You can, just create an XIB file, and customize your view there, then load the view like this:

```
MyCustomView* nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil][0];
```

Then just return it in your delegate function (Y) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add UI elements to `UIView` by using `addSubView:` method.

Something like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                           CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50.0)];

    //configure the UIView

    // Initialize an UIButton
    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    // Give it a title
    someButton.titleLabel.text = @"Touch me :3";

    // Add the button to the headerView
    [sectionHeaderView addSubView:someButton];

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

if you want different UIView's to different sections, use the `if` function:

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    // If this is the first section (0 section)
    if (section == 0) {
        UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                           CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50.0)];

        //configure the UIView

        // Initialize an UIButton
        UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

        // Give it a title
        someButton.titleLabel.text = @"Touch me On section One :3";

        // Add the button to the headerView
        [sectionHeaderView addSubView:someButton];

        return sectionHeaderView;
    }

    // If this is the second section (1 section)
    if (section == 1) {
        UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                           CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50.0)];

        //configure the UIView

        // Initialize an UIButton
        UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

        // Give it a title
        someButton.titleLabel.text = @"Touch me On sectio Two :3";

        // Add the button to the headerView
        [sectionHeaderView addSubView:someButton];

        return sectionHeaderView;
    }
    }
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through storyboard using prototype cells and then use tags for any UIButtons, UILabels, etc that you want to add to it.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
   UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HEADER_CELL"];

   // Stuff you want to do to your header
   // Tag can be anything except 0. You set this in the interface builder
   UILabel * myHeaderLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
   UIButton * myHeaderButton = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:2];

   myHeaderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d", section];

   myHeaderButton.title = @"Button Title";
   // headerButtonClicked is a function you want the button to do
   [myHeaderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(headerButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   return cell; 
}
```

Create a function for when the button was clicked

```
-(void)viewActivityMoreInfo:(id)sender 
{
   UIButton *btnClicked = (UIButton *) sender;
   // do something here
}
```